# Save battery by switching to 2G after a few minutes of inactivity

Tags: battery, battery-life, samsung-galaxy-note

I'm looking for an app that'll switch to 2G only after a few minutes of inactivity. The idea seems simple enough, but I can't find it.

JuiceDefender just disables the data connection, and re-enables it every 5-15 minutes. But that's a bit too restrictive for me.

Comment: Use `Tasker`… It supports all such type of automations..

Comment: AutomateIt is a free alternative to Tasker which has similar utilities: https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=AutomateIt.mainPackage

Comment: my phone/provider seems to do this automatically. most of the time it is connected via 2g. when surfing to a new page it switches to 3g and after some inactivity it goes back to 2g.

Comment: Tasker is able to do it, but only on Cyanogen.

Answer (score 3):

JuiceDefender can do this. It also can turn off data completely, and turn it on every 5 minutes or so to let stuff sync.

Comment: Can the free edition do this? And an unrooted device? Because I can only choose to turn it off, not switch to 3G.

Comment: @skerit: Yes, the free version on an unrooted device can also work to turn of data.